# How to use F# Power Pack in Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, f#

I wanted to use F# Power Pack in Windows Phone 7.1 application but it does not work.

If I just reference and use Power Pack in WP7 app it complains about mscorlib. Power Pack references classic .NET mscorlib but WP7 has its own version, which is not compatibale.

**Edit**: As Robert says, Power Pack has version for silverlight which should be used (located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0\Silverlight\v4.0\FSharp.PowerPack.dll").

But Even if I reference the correct version of Power Pack, exception is thrown when I try use something from it.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing.LexBuffer`1' from assembly 'FSharp.PowerPack, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99CF57B64B44BF93'.
```

The exception is thrown before entering to the method with:

```
var x = LexBuffer<char>.FromString("asdf"); // usage of PowerPack
```

This can be caused if incorrect version of PowerPack dll is loaded at runtime, but Modules window shows just this path:

```
\Applications\Install\152F0408-C230-4FDD-93E1-78660547C6B8\Install\FSharp.PowerPack.dll
```

I am also pretty sure, that everything I reference are Silverlight DLLs only and the application is running at WP emulator.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The F# PowerPack comes with a silverlight version too, so it's this you should be using. In the version of the powerpack I have installed the silverlight assemblies are installed under:
C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0\Silverlight

Edit:

I think Windows Phone 7 is compatible with Silverlight 3 were as Windows Phone 7.5 (mango) is compatible with Silverlight 4, so you may need to change the version of Silverlight depending on the version of Windows Phone you're targeting.

Comment: Thx, sounds great but if I use this reference in my F# project (which is linked to WP7) I get Exception on execution: Could not load type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing.LexBuffer`1' from assembly 'FSharp.PowerPack, Version=2.0.0.0, ...'.

Comment: Type load exception usual occur because your compiling the app against one version of an assembly, but a different version is loaded at runtime, but it doesn't sound like this is the case for you. It's pretty hard debug this without access to the source, but a few things you might try are: 1) ensure all assemblies referenced are silverlight, 2) use the debug > windows > modules window to identify where the assembly is loaded from, 3) look down the exception stack trace to find the bit of code trying to load the assembly and ensure it's compiled using silverlight

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect current problem, the previous one was just my fault to not referencing correct version of the Power Pack, but thanks to solving it :)

Comment: Ok, I've deleted old solution and configured everything from scratch and it "works". But If I linked F# (silverlight) project which is using FsLex and FsYacc, exception (Could not load type 'System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=3.7.0.0, ...) was thrown, but it is probably worth another question. Thanks.